# I want to stop user to input in a specific moment by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea where I have created a limitations of 0/150 word the 0 number increases 1, 2, 3 like that and when it goes to 150/150 I want that textarea not to take more inputs now I have tried to disable the textarea it works but user cant undo their text so actually I want that it stop taking more inputs plus user can undo their changes not disabling the textarea

```
if(document.getElementById("maximum_length").innerText==150){
  document.getElementById("pro_desc").disabled = true;
}
else if(document.getElementById("maximum_length").innerText<=150){
  let current = document.getElementById("maximum_length").innerText
  document.getElementById("maximum_length").innerText = Number(current) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Check if this helps you out [Textarea Characters Limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5607015/15405352)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent input to a textarea after a certain character count is reached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088102/how-to-prevent-input-to-a-textarea-after-a-certain-character-count-is-reached)

Comment: textarea tags support a `maxlength` attribute. You can use that. https://jsfiddle.net/1yrkob0x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `maxlength` attribute:

```
<textarea maxlength="150">
```

Comment: shoot!! man I forget HTML has the power I am using js for no reason thanks for reminding!